# How do I use an Embedded database with the Entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, embedded-database

I was wondering about the use of the .NET entity framework with an embedded database solution. Right now, I only use the EF with SQL Server but for a new project I'm looking for alternate solutions. [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) would be one solution, but are there other alternatives that I can use with EF? Preferably solutions that don't require complex installations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual (although not the full one) list of ADO.NET Entity Framework providers is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx). 
There is a couple of providers supporting Embedded MySQL - [dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) and [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and SQLite - [dotConnect for SQLite](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/) and [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If there is an EF provider for the embedded database, you should be able to plug it right into EF.  Check with your embedded database provider to see if they have support for EF.

**Third Party Provider Support for the Entity Framework**
http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/08/11/third-party-provider-support-for-the-entity-framework-rtm.aspx